# jQuery id-begins-with trigger not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a very strange thing happening to me. I have never seen this before. I am not very knowledgeable in jQuery/Javascript, but to my untrained eye, this looks insane...

What is happening is that without the `alert('hello')` under the `$(document).ready` function, the ID-begins-with selector does not trigger (i.e., does not alert the "goodbye"). If I add the `alert('hello')` below the `$(document).ready)` function, suddenly, the `alert('goodbye')` words.

How is this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('hello');
        $('a[id^="hash-"]').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('goodbye');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have also tried with .on():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('hello');
        $('a[id^="hash-"]').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('goodbye');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The HTML element is initially added on page load, but can be changed if you filter the bootgrid table, hence I changed it to `.on()` as suggested in the comments.

```
<td>
    <a id="hash-1" href="#" data-row-id="1">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-left-bottom" title="Select this site"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

I then tried this (because the original `<td>` where the icon resides is also dynamically created):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[id^="hash-"]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('goodbye');
});
```

Also unsuccessful...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you adding the elements on page?

Comment: Check if the event is actually bound to the element. Use the `on` method instead of `click` if you need to delegate events

Comment: Are the elements being added dynamically? My instinct says "yes"

Comment: load comes AFTER ready if you are talking about onload.

Comment: The only reason I could see this happening is if the elements are appended to the DOM after the page loads. In which case you need to use a delegated event handler: `$(document).on('click', 'a[id^="hash-"]', fn);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: `$('a[id^="hash-"]').click(function(){})` and `$('a[id^="hash-"]').on('click', function(){})` are the same thing.

Comment: Edited the question to show what I have tried based on the comments, and still not working :-( Thanks for the comments so far!

Comment: `$('a[id^=hash]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
         alert('goodbye');
        });` please try this code @KobusMyburgh

Comment: @ubm, I have tried that before - no luck...

Comment: oh ..it works for me,did you include jquery library properly?@KobusMyburgh

Comment: @ubm if you read the question properly, you will see that it does work in certain cases, so yes, my jQuery is loaded properly.

Comment: are the rows and links loaded dynamically(after loading page)@KobusMyburgh

Comment: @ubm please read the question. It is all in there.

Comment: @epascarello, thanks - I have changed the question accordingly after your last comment to use .on() properly (I think). I am still not getting it to work?

Comment: i think, newly added elements doesn't get this function@KobusMyburgh

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'a[id^="hash-"]', fn);` as posted above by @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @epascarello I have edited the question, particularly the part at the 4th code block. Doing what Rory McCrossan and you said. I am still not getting it to work :-(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gg2koh9L/ works so what is different?

Comment: @epascarello, thank you - that (`$('table tbody')`) worked, but `$(document)` did not. Not sure why, but if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score -3):

This is working fine for me.

```js
$(document).on('click','a[id^="hash-"]',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('goodbye' + $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a id="hash-1">1</a> 
    <a id="hash-2">2</a> 
    <a id="hash-3">3</a> 
    <a id="hash-4">4</a>
```

Comment: because your code is executing after the elements are on the page.

Comment: @epascarello, I have applied delegation click even with on() method no remove down vote please